# Flex: how to select each element/instance of a repeater

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, repeater

I'll explain my problem as brief as possible. I have a variable bandName, the value is String that i get through an API.

```
        public function haalNaam(selectedChart:Object):String 
        {
            var bandName:String = selectedChart.name;
        }
```

I use this var in a repeater for a label. This repeater repeats 5 times, so it shows the 5 most hyped artists:

```
        <repeater>
            <label text="{haalNaam(lastfmCollection.currentItem)}"/>
        </repeater>
```

Next, i had to transport the var bandName to another component. I managed to do this with this command:

```
var theName = "LastFmApi(this.parentApplication).bandName".
```

This code works, but I only manage to get the bandName of the last element in the repeater (5th one). I have no idea how i can
receive the names of the artists 1,2,3 or 4. How can i get to those values?

Comment: Oh... I had no idea haha. i reviewed previous questions and selected answers as apporpriate. i'll make sure to do that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

First, it doesn't look like what you've pasted in is functional code (your haalName function doesn't return anything, and your repeater doesn't have the id referred to in the label).

Second, why don't you just use lastfmCollection.currentItem.name in the label's text property, and skip the function call?

Third, you don't say exactly what the goal is, so I'll assume that you want to click one of the items in the repeater and put the label text in the variable theName.  That would look like this:

theName=(event.target as Label).text;

Note that you may also want to consider using a DataGroup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my code for this question to try and make it clearer. Thanks for the tip, i'll skip that function call from now on. And yes, that's what i meant. I understand what the solution is, but i'm not sure how i should implement in my rpoject. Could you elaborate a bit on it? Many thanks!

Comment: I mean that i edited my code before posting because my full code is messy. Anyway, i uploaded the main page and component on pastebin. I know many things aren't really well programmed, but this is more like a learning project and soon i'll remake the whole thing with the stuff i'm learning now. i hope this can help. Really thank you so much for putting your time into this! pastebin link for main: http://pastebin.com/JzGZ4ut4 and profile component: http://pastebin.com/0UfCPs3u

Comment: Got it! On the namelabels:

click = "event.currentTarget.getRepeaterItem().name" where name is what is declared in the xml as the artist name.

and the function:

   public function handleclick(cName:String):void
   {
    somelabel.text = cName;
   }